# Help combining two scripts

Tags: gpio, python, python-3

I know this is very blatant but I really need help with my python scripts right now.

I have following two scripts or one script and a class if you will so.

```
import sys
import time
import pigpio

inactive = False

def cbf(GPIO, level, tick):
   global inactive
   if level == pigpio.TIMEOUT:
      if inactive == False:
         inactive = True
         self.on_goal 
   else:
      if inactive == True:
         inactive = False
         self.on_goal
pi = pigpio.pi()


pin_number = 23

cb = pi.callback(pin_number, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, cbf)
pi.set_watchdog(pin_number, 30) # get alert if quiet for 30 milliseconds
```

This script reads from an ir sensor and switches "inactive" around once the sensor stops getting a signal and the other way around.

```
class GoalDetector:

    def __init__(self, bus, pin_number, team):
        self.bus = bus
        self.pin = pin_number
        self.team = team

        if self.pin: #Kontrolle Pin vorhanden
            #GPIO.setup(self.pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
            #GPIO.setup(self.pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)
            #GPIO.add_event_detect(self.pin, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.on_goal, bouncetime=10)


        else: #wenn pin nicht vorhanden
            logger.warn("Cannot init GoalDetector {0}, pin not specified".format(self.team))

    def __del__(self):
        if self.pin:
            GPIO.remove_event_detect(self.pin)

    def on_goal(self, channel):
        logger.info("Goal {}!".format(self.team))
        self.bus.notify('goal_event', {'source': 'rpi', 'team': self.team})
```

This class was once supposed to do that, but because of the way my sensor works I have to use the script above.

I don't seem to be able to include the first script in my class without breaking it. If I understand this right, all the first script has to achieve is calling  on_goal.

Is someone willing to help me with this? I'm really counting on your help right now.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You mention your script breaks - how so? Do you get an error message that you could include? On skimming the code, I see a few potential problems such as writing `self.on_goal` to try and call the functions, without using the appropriate brackets (e.g. `self.on_goal(foo, bar)` *would* invoke it). A glaring issue there though is that `cbf` isn't in a class and doesn't have a `self` parameter, so it can't call that anyway. Unfortunately, I don't think this question is a good fit here, and arguably it's not specifically Pi-related so you'd be best to ask on a programming site. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I agree, not very pi related. I do not get an error message in any way, everything just stops working, that's why it's so hard for me.

Comment: in Function `cbf` "`self`" is not defined in the function signature, in C this would be a compilation error, but due to python's duck typing and is likely  not throwing an error because there is 'self' in the callback context it is called in when the callback executes, but not the `self` you are actually looking for (GoalDetector instance) . There is no reason you cannot implement cbf as a method in `GoalDetector`,  in that context self will be bound correcly.

Answer (score 1):

You define a callback function with the variable `self` in the logic

```
def cbf(GPIO, level, tick):
   global inactive
   if level == pigpio.TIMEOUT:
      if inactive == False:
         inactive = True
         self.on_goal #### <----------------HERE
   else:
      if inactive == True:
         inactive = False
         self.on_goal ### <----------------HERE
```

Unlike in Java, or C++, `self` is not automatically available in any context. It is passed to the function as the first variable, and is computed dynamically during the method call this is why methods are defined as `def my_method(self, var1, var2....)`

If you were to simply execute `cbf` you would likely have an error, since `self` is not defined.

Most likely,  callback simply never gets called and an error is never detected.

However, since `cbf` is called in a callback context, which is itself may be an instance of some object, there is a chance that `self` that exists, but is not the `self` you are looking for (your Handler Class)

Illustrative psuedocode

```
def proto_callback_processor(self, cb, *args, **kwargs):
   cb(*args, **kwargs) ##<---- This call will have a "self" available as variable but this is the callback/pigpio instance
```

You are also mixing `GPIO` and `pigpio` calls, which is not recommended, these are both libraries implementing similar functionality, but will conflict and not play nice together on a high level.

My suggestion is to define the callback as part of the class with a global `pigpio` object.

```
import sys
import time
import pigpio

pi = pigpio.pi()
class GoalDetector:

    def __init__(self, bus, pin_number, team):
        self.bus = bus
        self.pin = pin_number
        self.team = team
        self.inactive = False

        if self.pin: #Kontrolle Pin vorhanden
            #Add addtional gpio initialization 
            #Note, you can also simply use GPIO event as well.
            self.cb = pi.callback(pin_number, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, self.cbf)
            pi.set_watchdog(pin_number, 30) # get alert if quiet for 30 milliseconds


        else: #wenn pin nicht vorhanden
            logger.warn("Cannot init GoalDetector {0}, pin not specified".format(self.team))

    def __del__(self):
        if self.pin:
            self.cb.cancel()

    def on_goal(self):
        logger.info("Goal {}!".format(self.team))
        self.bus.notify('goal_event', {'source': 'rpi', 'team': self.team})

    def cbf(self, GPIO, level, tick):
      if level == pigpio.TIMEOUT and not self.inactive:
         self.inactive = True
         self.on_goal()
      elif  self.inactive:
         self.inactive = False
         self.on_goal() ### <----------------HERE

if __name__ == "__main__":
  #Example execution
  pin23_goal = GoalDetector(1,1,23)

  # you can also register CB externally
  blank_goal = GoalDetector(1,1,None)
  cb = pi.callback(23, pigpio.EITHER_EDGE, blank_goal.cbf)
  pi.set_watchdog(pin_number, 30) # get alert if quiet for 30 milliseconds

  #run forever
  while(True):
    time.sleep(1)
```

There are many other ways to organize this, you can define the callback to be a standalone function or static method, and lookup your high level handler based on dictionary or some other mechanism.

But you get the idea and it should be enough for you to start.